# Upgrade from trac 0.10.3 to 0.12 mod_python database error

Tags: trac

I´m trying to upgrade trac! from 0.10.3 to 0.12. Need help, i basiclally did steps shown here

http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracUpgrade

**So i went through this commands without errors:**

todasana:~# easy_install —upgrade Trac0.12 Searching for Trac0.12

---

todasana:~# trac-admin /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/trac_catw3 upgrade

---

todasana:~# trac-admin /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/trac_catw3 wiki upgrade

---

todasana:~# trac-admin /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/trac_catw3 repository resync ‘*’

---

*Didn´t do Step 5 Refresh static resources, because i did not understand it, and i think it does not apply to me: trac-admin /path/to/env deploy /deploy/path*

then i 
**restarted apache:
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart**

got this error in the browser now:
Mod_python error: "PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 299, in HandlerDispatch
    result = object(req)
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/web/modpython_frontend.py", line 87, in handler
    gateway.run(dispatch_request)
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/web/wsgi.py", line 87, in run
    response = application(self.environ, self._start_response)
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/web/main.py", line 377, in dispatch_request
    env = _open_environment(env_path, run_once=run_once)
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/web/main.py", line 58, in _open_environment
    env_cache[env_path] = open_environment(env_path)
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/env.py", line 435, in open_environment
    if env.needs_upgrade():
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/env.py", line 315, in needs_upgrade
    if participant.environment_needs_upgrade(db):
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/env.py", line 373, in environment_needs_upgrade
    raise TracError, 'Database newer than Trac version'

**TracError: Database newer than Trac version**

*got Python 2.4.4 (#2, Jan 24 2010, 11:19:18)

mysql: Server version: 5.0.32-Debian_7etch11-log Debian etch distribution*

**IT OCCOURS TO ME THAT SOMETHING SHOULD BE DONE WITH THE DATABASE OR CONFIG FILES, BUT NOT SURE   WHAT BECAUSE THERE IS NOTHING IN THE DOCS ABOUT IT!

Guys have a great day!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the version of Trac being run by Apache is the older version and not the version you just installed.  Verify that the version of Trac you are running is the version you think you are running.

Comment: you were right, i re-installed everything and is working fino now. THANKYOU